# Jquery onchange function does not get called on hidden file control

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to call onchange function on selection of file or when file is changed, but my onchange function does not gets called because i have set display:none for file control because i am using calling it on image click, I can't understand how to call it on onchange function:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#profile-image').on('click', function() {
    $('#photo').click(); // opens up the file dialog for selection of image
  });
});

$("#photo").change(function() {
  alert($(this).val())
});
```

```css
.hidden_img {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="hidden_img" type="file" name="imagefile" id="photo"/>
<img src="images/btn.jpg" width="148" height="60" alt="btn" id="profile-image">
```

Comment: But your same code **[here](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/Loc11fzh/)** works fine!!!

Comment: It works fine, you can have look at "[http://jsfiddle.net/prateeksarve/x9z8qgqk/][1]"

Comment: Yes , its working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Please check below solution, it works fine;

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#profile-image').on('click', function() {
    $('#photo').click(); // opens up the file dialog for selection of image
  });
});

$("#photo").on('change',function() {
  alert($(this).val())
});
```

```css
#photo{
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input class="hidden_img" type="file" name="imagefile" id="photo" />
<img src="http://placehold.it/148X60" width="148" height="60" alt="btn" id="profile-image">
```

Comment: Saying 'what you have already works' should be a comment, not an answer. If the OP is having issues with their code then there must be a problem elsewhere, which means this will not help.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan This is probably my bad, the snippet I posted in the question wasn't representative of the OP's problem so this answer kind of added the necessary CSS & jQuery requirements to show how it should work